# SSH2 connection issues on Ubuntu 14.04 - it randomly works when it wants to

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, eclipse, c++

So I've been digging around for a solution and cannot find an answer for this.
Setup: I am using Eclipse Mars (v4.5) running on Win7 with a Linaro ARM-Linux tool chain. Eclipse has a remote host setup (SSH Only connection) through Ethernet to a Wandboard running Ubuntu 14.04. When I run an application I have a C/C++ Remote Application configuration properly setup in Eclipse and the file does transfer to the Wandboard, the file then executes and I can see the console output back on Eclipse (like everything should be). I can even attach the gdbserver to my executable and do remote debugging.
Problem: This will work but only sometimes and a lot of the time I get a connection error in Eclipse (RSEG1058 - Connect to 192.168.x.xxx was cancelled). Below is the output from /var/log/auth.log when this occurs:

```
Aug 11 17:35:28 wandboard sshd[21453]: Accepted password for ubuntu from 192.168.6.236 port 1388 ssh2
Aug 11 17:35:28 wandboard sshd[21453]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
Aug 11 17:36:09 wandboard sshd[21491]: fatal: mm_request_receive: read: bad msg_len -1660944384
Aug 11 17:36:09 wandboard sshd[21476]: fatal: mm_request_receive_expect: read: rtype 60 != type 29
Aug 11 17:36:09 wandboard sshd[21453]: fatal: mm_request_receive: read: Connection reset by peer
Aug 11 17:36:09 wandboard sshd[21453]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user Ubuntu
```

Sometimes I will get:

```
Aug 11 17:14:51 wandboard sshd[21021]: Accepted password for ubuntu from 192.168.6.236 port 3266 ssh2
Aug 11 17:14:51 wandboard sshd[21021]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
Aug 11 17:14:51 wandboard sshd[21044]: fatal: mm_request_receive_expect: read: rtype 157 != type 29
Aug 11 17:14:51 wandboard sshd[21049]: fatal: mm_request_receive_expect: read: rtype 29 != type 157
Aug 11 17:14:51 wandboard sshd[21021]: fatal: mm_request_receive: read: Connection reset by peer
Aug 11 17:14:51 wandboard sshd[21021]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user Ubuntu
```

It will all work at first, then after a few successful connections it will stop working. Once a lot of time passes (I've never measured this) it will start working again.

Note: I was using a USB to Ethernet adapter to connect the Wandboard to my PC and could only get a connection 1 out of 10 times. I then connected my Wandboard to the same network as my PC and now I get 4 or 5 connections before it stops working again.

I've also asked this question on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953443/ssh2-connection-issues-on-ubuntu-14-04-it-randomly-works-when-it-wants-to) but was asked to move it to this site.

Comment: Have you ever tried to diagnose the network traffic with a tool like for example wireshark ( https://www.wireshark.org/ ).  This could give some insight.

Answer (score 0):

This Ubuntu issue with multiplexed SSH connections may match your problem/issue:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/1334916